# How to change a running variable in python

Tags: python, list, performance, variables

I am trying to build a program that, given a list of tuples and an integer, prints all the tuples were every element can be divided by k. It is important, that the information is entered using input().
So for example, if I type: [(6, 24, 12),(60, 12, 6),(12, 18, 21)] and 6, the output would be [(6, 24, 12),(60, 12, 6 )].
However, I can't seem to change the running variable y and I don't know what I am doing wrong, because I also don't generate any output. Additionally to solving the problem with the idea that you can see in my code below, I am happy to receive other, more efficient suggestions, because it seems like a very complicated solution to me, I just could not think of something else.
Thank you so much!

```
def dos():
    temp = True
    lista = input()
    k = input()
    count = 0
    lista = lista.split('),(') # split the string into different parts corresponding to the entered tuples
    for x in range(len(lista) - 1): # for all elements of the list
        for y in range(len(lista[0])): # go through the list elements 
            if ((lista[x])[y - 1:y]).isdigit(): #is our sign a number or a comma/something else?
                while ((lista[x])[y:y + 1]).isdigit(): # make sure we include numbers with more than one digit
                    count = count + 1 # count how many digits our number has
                    y += 1 # skip ahead as to not repeat the following digits
                if (int(((lista[x])[y - (count + 1):y])) % int(k)) != 0: # if our number can't be divided by the input
                    temp = False
                count = 0
        if temp: # if we did not encounter a number that cant be divided by our integer
            print(lista[x])
        temp = True
```

Comment: The values taken on by the variable in a `for` loop are defined solely by the loop's iterator; changes made to the variable yourself have absolutely no effect on the iterator.  You would need to rewrite the loop as a `while` if you want to be able to manipulate the variable like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to match the tuple strings, but also to identify the individual integers with each string and thereby create actual python tuples which you can check for your divisible condition.

```
import re
def dos():
    lista = input()
    k = int(input())
    
    found = []
    for items in re.findall(r'\([-\d, ]+\)', lista):
        tup = tuple(map(int, re.findall(r'-?\d+', items)))
        if all([i % k == 0 for i in tup]):
            found.append(tup)
    return found
```

Comment: I edited my answer a couple of times to cover the case of the integer being negative